# Is it allowed to redistribute a modification of BSD licensed software on OSSRH with my Maven groupId?

Tags: bsd, redistribution

I modified a BSD licensed software and proposed the patch to the contributors. I has been discussed and refused. I'm respecting the decision not to merge the changes, however I want to provide the modification in an easy accessible way.

I have an [OSSRH](https://central.sonatype.org/pages/ossrh-guide.html) account for a namespace that differs from the namespace of the original software. Is it ok if I upload the original software + my changes + a modification to `build.gradle` with my OSSRH namespace?

The text of the license is

```
BSD License

Copyright (c) 2000-2015 www.hamcrest.org
All rights reserved.

Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:

Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this list of
conditions and the following disclaimer. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce
the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in
the documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.

Neither the name of Hamcrest nor the names of its contributors may be used to endorse
or promote products derived from this software without specific prior written
permission.

THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" AND ANY
EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES
OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT
SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT,
INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED
TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR
BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN
CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY
WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH
DAMAGE.
```

I'm aware of alternative ways of distributing my modification. I'm interested in the correctness of this particular approach.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is allowed.

The license explicitly gives permission to distribute the software with modifications. The only conditions to that are that you retain the copyright notice and license text.

For your changes, you can put in your own copyright notice.